# ESP8266 and Arduino integration

Tags: esp8266

I am trying to upload a sketch and getting below error:

```
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed.
```

Connections:

```
TX - TX
CH_PD - 3.3 V
RX - RX
VCC - 3.3
GPIO GND
GND - GND
```

Before uploading the sketch I have reset the arduino and ESP and selected board as ESP8266 and baud rate as 115200 but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what you're using to program it (an FTDI board? the USB adapter on an Arduino?) but you probably want to connect

```
TX - RX
RX - TX
```